# Why do console OSes use gray text instead of white?

Tags: user-interface, colors, console, usability, vga

I often use operating systems without GUI, and I'm also developing mine. I've noticed that, although VGA 80x25 mode supports 0xF color, which stands for white, everyone uses 0x7, which stands for gray, for text color. Why doesn't one use white? After all, it's easier to see it with black background.

P.S. I'm sorry if I've made any mistakes, English isn't my native language.

Comment: With the most commong displays and settings white on black is not easier to see, it's too strong, it's distressing

Answer (score 0):

Because the names of the colors are confusing.

- 0x07 looks like a bight grey, but it's called "white"
- 0x08 looks like a dark grey, but it's called "grey"
- 0x0F looks like white, but it's called "white (high intensity)"

So if you are a developer and you look in the table for white you will find that 0x07 is white and might not see the second entry at the bottom of the table (0x0F) because you think you already found the ID for white. So real white is 0x0F and using 0x07 as white is a bug caused by the confusing names.